# Can AWS API Gateway automatically add correlation (request) ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a set of microservices running on ECS which are deployed behind the API Gateway which forwards the client calls to the service endpoints.
I would like to use correlation (request) IDs in my services so that I can easier relate the events and everything that happens on the backend and the client requests.

Is there a possibility to configure AWS API Gateway to automatically add auto-generated (unique) correlation ID as a header of the request before it's forwarded to my backend services?

Comment: Take a look at this [blog article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/techniques-and-tools-for-better-serverless-api-logging-with-amazon-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda/) for information on the already existing `x-amzn-RequestId` header.

Comment: I saw that article but it talks about how a request id is generated for Lambdas, I would like to have the same for the rest calls issued to my microservices running as containers on the Fargate

Comment: The APIGW portion is still relevant for ECS. You can map the `context.requestId` parameter to an HTTP header such as `X-Request-Id` and use that as a correlation ID.